# MSBuild ignoring /p:Configuration for one click deployments

Tags: msbuild

I'm using MS Build inside a TFS build definition to create a One Click deployment.

Everything is working great but MS Build is ignoring `/p:Configuration` and using the default `app.config` instead of the required `app.dev.config` when creating the `exe.config.deploy`.

Is there a difference property that I should be using?

Here is the MS Build I am using.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\70\UTI-IT\LMSIntegrationTool_CO_QA2\Sources\src\LMSIntegrationTool\LMSScheduling.sln" /m:1 /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\70\UTI-IT\LMSIntegrationTool_CO_QA2\Sources\src\LMSIntegrationTool\LMSScheduling.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=diagnostic" /target:publish /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configuration=DEV /p:DeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MsDeployServiceURL=corpdevweb11 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:ApplicationVersion=1.0.30301.5 /p:OutDir=\\prdtfsbld01\drops\LMSSchedulerTest\\ /p:PublishDir=\\prdtfsbld01\drops\LMSSchedulerTest\\ /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\70\UTI-IT\LMSIntegrationTool_CO_QA2\Binaries\\" /p:RunCodeAnalysis="False"
```

Comment: Any reason for the 2 output directories? - `/p=OutDir=`

Comment: Good catch.  I'd not noticed that before.

Comment: @RichardButterwood, does that solve the problem? If so, you may post that in answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Slow Cheetah wasn't installed on the build server.  Thank you for the responses.

Comment: please, mark the quetion as answered, so people see the resolution when they search